# How to send base64 url data using json from javascript client to nodejs server using websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tring to send the base64 url from javascript to nodejs, but I am not getting a proper way to do that. If someone knows please help ! Thank you.

Here is the code I tried,

Client.js

```
 var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
 var encoded = btoa(JSON.stringify(image));
 connection.send(encoded);
```

Server.js

```
connection.on('message', function(message){

           console.log("Message: "+message);
            if (message.type === 'utf8') { // accept only text
                var post = Buffer.from(message.data).toString('base64');
                 console.log("post: "+post);
            }
});
```

Which an error:

```
Message: [object Object]
buffer.js:207
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
```

Thank you !!

Comment: can you add your sample output

Comment: I want to display the base64 data on server side console. Currently I am getting an error mentioned above.

Comment: I want to know what you are getting in 'message.data' I think its not a valid JSON object

Comment: Hi, sorry, solved the error. Will post the answer here. Thank you so much for you reply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

Client

```
 var base64 = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
 connection.send(base64);
```

Server

```
connection.on('message', function (message) {

    console.log("Message: " + message);
    if (message.type === 'utf8') { // accept only text
        var post = message.utf8Data;
        console.log("post: " + post);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank for you reply :). but this gives output as : Message: [object Object]
post: undefined

Comment: We have to take utf8Data. so var post = message.utf8Data; is correct. Thanks for you answer.